# Prevent multi select box to not change in multi check box on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How to prevent multi select box to not change the view on mobile browser into checkbox?

Already tried the data-role="none" attribute but not working.

```
  <select multiple="multiple" data-role="none">
        <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
        <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
        <option value="GBP">British Pound Sterling</option>
  </select>
```

Currently the output for this multi select box for mobile browser is shown in checkbox, and I want this as a default view of multi select box in mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `data-role="none"`, but you can use the data attribute: `data-native-menu="false".`

From the [docs](https://api.jquerymobile.com/1.4/selectmenu/#option-nativeMenu): "When set to `true`, clicking the custom-styled select menu will open the native select menu which is best for performance. If set to `false`, the custom select menu style will be used instead of the native menu."

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
  <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
  <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
  <option value="GBP">British Pound Sterling</option>
</select>
```